# How to report the Obsolete assets in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-billing

I want to send an Email with all the obsolete assets in Azure that are no longer actively used within 3 months. I need to send this email every day. There is no Azure native option available. Am I missing any built-in method which can be used?

Comment: Are you planning to code this yourself? Otherwise you're asking this in the wrong place, since StackOverflow is for programming questions only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no native way to send such report, so you need to prepare your own solution. This would involve steps:

- tag obsolete assets
- query all resources with specific tag ([Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json#list-by-tag), [AzCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list))
- process query result to see them as report you like (azure function, logic app)
- send report by mail (azure function, logic app)

Example almost ready to use you may find at https://www.blueboxes.co.uk/how-to-create-azure-resource-graph-explorer-scheduled-reports-and-email-alerts